# Expected comma but found indent / Expected eof but found }

Tags: javascript

Have two errors in this bit of js and can't for the life of me figure them. Total novice, sorry... Have already trawled through a good few answers and articles to no avail.

Errors are on lines 50 and 53(marked for your convenience)

First question, be nice...

```
    $(function() {
    // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
    // It has the name attribute "registration"
    $("form[name='registration']").validate({

    errorElement: 'div',
            rules: {
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required",
            email: {
            required: true,
                    validEmail: true
            },
            university: {
            required: true,
                    minlength: 2
            },
            pass_one: {
            required: true,
                    minlength: 5
            },
            pass_two: {
            required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
            },
    },
    messages: {
    first_name: "Please enter your firstname",
            last_name: "Please enter your lastname",
            university: {
            required: "Please enter your university",
                    minlength: "Must be at least 2 charachters"
            },
            pass_one: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Password must be at least 5 charachters 
    long"
            },
            pass_two: {
            required: "Please re-enter password",
                    minlength: "Must be 5 charchters long",
                    equalTo: "passwords do not match poo face"
            }

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
    }

    /*50*/        JQuery.validator.addMethod("validEmail", function(value, element) {
               return this.optional(element) || /^.+@ul.ie$/.test(value);
            }, "Only UL email addresses are allowed.");
    /*53*/  });

    });
```

Comment: I believe it expects a comma after the bracket on line 49.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Password must be at least 5 charachters 
long"
```

has a newline in it. That's not how multi-line strings work in JS.

These lines:

```
JQuery.validator.addMethod("validEmail", function(value, element) { //etc
```

should live elsewhere, not in the `validate` object parameter.